# How to return a datetime that can be converted based on different locales?

Tags: php, timezone, locale

We are developing an API in PHP, MySQL that one of its fields returns a datetime in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. This API in the very near future can be used in different continents. In which `ISO` format should I save my `datetime` that time offset can be preserved too?

Does this time do the job? Or should I use something like `ISO 8601`?

I've also read that in PHP we can return date/time with:

```
gmdate('Y-m-dTH:i:sZ');
```

What do you suggest? In what format should I return date/time?

Comment: As a UNIX timestamp. Unless your dates are prior to 1970.

Comment: @N.B. Dates range from 2000 to 2014. So you mean I use time() function?

Comment: Right, I apologize for not reading carefully the first time. When you deal with dates that can come from various time zones, what you should do is store it as a `timestamp` in MySQL. In that case, it becomes irrelevant where the information comes from (which continent). This is true for *saving* data. Now, when it comes to displaying date information to people on different continents, you would have to know their time zone. Using PHP's `DateTime`, you can use the timestamp from the database, pair it with `DateTimeZone` and show the correct time for that time zone.

Comment: Also, when you need to exchange data between various services - providing the `timestamp` allows the target application to apply any range of time zones for its own formatting purposes. However, all date storage should be without time zone reliance. That's why `timestamp` plays a huge utility role here - it's always UTC.

Comment: Please put your whole comments as an answer. tnx :--)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with dates that can come from various time zones, what you should do is store it as a timestamp in MySQL. In that case, it becomes irrelevant where the information comes from (which continent). This is true for saving data. Now, when it comes to displaying date information to people on different continents, you would have to know their time zone. Using PHP's `DateTime`, you can use the timestamp from the database, pair it with `DateTimeZone` and show the correct time for that time zone.

Also, when you need to exchange data between various services - providing the timestamp allows the target application to apply any range of time zones for its own formatting purposes. However, all date storage should be without time zone reliance. That's why timestamp plays a huge utility role here - it's always UTC.

Now, let's provide some code so this doesn't become just all-talk.

MySQL's `timestamp` data-type stores the value as integer internally, but displays it as datetime.

```
$mysql_datetime = '2014-10-15 12:58:55'; // this is what you got from the database

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysql_datetime); // Now you have the object which can manipulate dates

// Let's assume you have someone in New York who wants to see the date but formatted according to their time zone

$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $dt->format('Y.m.d, H:i:s'); // Format accepted is the same as for `date()` function.
```

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is not needed when you have standard datetime format like `Y-m-d H:i:s` (and many others). Simple `new DateTime()` would be enough.